# Ionic / Cordova Windows build picking up incorrect MSBUILD path

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

I have had to do a few update of Visual Studio on my Windows 10 machine (after some licensing issues).

I use to have Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, which I uninstalled. I now have Visual Studio Professional 2017, and Studio Enterprise 2019 (which I recently installed). I also installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 (2).

Now, when I try to build my Ionic project via the command I have always used...

```
ionic cordova build windows --prod --release -- --archs="x86 x64 arm" --buildConfig=platform_build_files\\windows\\build.config
```

I now get the error...

```
    Building project: D:\dev\myapp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
            Configuration : release
            Platform      : x86
            Buildflags    : /p:AppxBundle=Never,/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload
            MSBuildTools  : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
    buildProject spawn: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild [ 'D:\\dev\\myapp\\platforms\\windows\\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj',  '/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal',
      '/nologo',
      '/p:Configuration=release',
      '/p:Platform=x86',
      '/p:AppxBundle=Never',
      '/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload' ] { stdio: 'inherit' }
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target: Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

Of course I no longer have a folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise` as I uninstalled it.

I have removed and readded the windows platform for my Ionic app, but this did not help.

Also, I am not sure if this is related, but when I try to open the CordovaApp.sln in Visual Studio 2019, I get the following...

[image]

Not sure if related.

My question is, **how can I reset this MSBuild path**? I cannot see any environmental variables anywhere for this, I just can't get rid of this old path

### Edit 1

I added the env var as suggested:

[image]

Opened a new command prompt, but it is still looking for the non-existent path

> No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target: Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, creating UWP apps using `Javascript` is no longer supported, if you want to build UWP apps using web technologies like Cordova. You need to use Visual Studio 2017.

> My question is, how can I reset this MSBuild path?

Visual Studio will choose the version of MSBuild without explicit settings, but you can change this by setting environment variables.

Please add the path of MSBuild to the system environment variable, like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I added the above, but it does not seem to be using that path (screen shot in the question)

Comment: Sorry, it’s my problem. Please add the MSBuild path to `PATH` variable :)

Comment: I added the path to the PATH variable, but it is still finding the old non existent path. Perhaps it is a registry setting somewhere...

Comment: Hi, It seems that this is not a valid MSBuild path. Have you tried building your app using Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Good point.Just tried then, and I get `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'winapifamily.h': No such file or directory SQLite3.UWP c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt\corecrt.h 196`. So must be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487627/ionic-cordova-sqlite-plugin-windows-cannot-open-include-file-winapifamily-h)